# CakePHP auth component doesn't login users

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

this is my AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginAction' => array(
                'controller' => 'students',
                'action' => 'login'
            ),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'students', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'students', 'action' => 'login'),
            'authError' => "You can't acces that page",
            'authorize' => array('controller')
        )
    );

    public function isAuthorized($student){
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

this is my StudentsController.php

```
class StudentsController extends AppController{


        public function login(){
            if($this->request->is('post')){
                if($this->Auth->login()){
                    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
                }else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Your username or password is incorrect');
                }
            }
        }

        public function logout(){
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
        }
}
```

this is my login.ctp

```
<h2>Login</h2>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create();
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
```

and in my db the table name is *students* and its fields are *username* and *password*.

But every time I try to login with `$this->Auth->login()`, it returns false and password wrong flash message is showing and I cannot login.

Comment: Duplicate of hundred others like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011029/cakephp-auth-component-not-working - where one forgot to include the Auth adapters (Form in particular).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using an other model than `Users` for authentication, you need to provide that model name to the `AuthComponent`.

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    AuthComponent::ALL => array('userModel' => 'Student'),
    'Form',
    'Basic'
);
```

You should read the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)